# Geiser: unbound identifier in module

Tags: racket, geiser

I am attempting to install Geiser (for Racket) on Ubuntu.

I have run:

`sudo apt-get install geiser`

and have appended to my .emacs file the line:

`(load-file "~/lisp/geiser/elisp/geiser.el")` (I double checked the path.)

I restart Emacs, use `M-x run-geiser` and received the following error:

`compile: unbound identifier in module in: ~a` at `modules.rkt:99:60`

I attempted to build from source but I after running

`sudo make install` within the directory, I receive the error that `make install` is not a target. (I retrieved the source via Git).

If I run `./autogen.sh` to generate the target, I receive: `autoreconf: not found`.

Am I missing a step or doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run `./autogen.sh` I needed the package `dh-autogen`.

In order to run `make install` I needed the package `texinfo`.

Finally, in order to make `run-geiser` work I needed to place

```
(require 'geiser-install)
```

in my `.emacs` file (as per the site's instructions).

So it was just two missing packages.